# How to encrypt API keys for Travis CI configuration with bash cli (without ruby)?

Tags: ruby, bash, encryption, travis-ci

I've been reading in the [Travis CI documentation about the encryption](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/#Usage) of API access keys and they suggest to use their ruby gem. Is there another way to do it, so I don't have to install a whole ruby environment and login with my GitHub credentials?

As described in [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/#Fetching-the-public-key-for-your-repository) the public key can be downloaded easily. Is it somehow possible to use it with openssl or so and get the same result as if I use `travis encrypt`?

Comment: I was not sure whether I should post this here or on Superusers :S

Comment: This one's right on the fence since Travis sort of straddles both domains. As far as I know the `travis` command is Ruby-based, so you're sort of stuck with Ruby as a dependency unless you can find a compatible alternative.

Comment: I *think* the encryption code is AES as shown here: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-core/blob/fd905d451087627e1d7320585b10c5bf75d6ad40/lib/travis/model/encrypted_column.rb#L67 (and then line 75 is where it's base64-encoded).  But I don't use travis so I can't be certain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this problem, I've created a little bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() { echo -e "Travis Encrypt Script\nUsage:\t$0 \n -r\t<username/repository> \n -e\t<string which should be encrypted>" 1>&2; exit 1; }

while getopts ":r:e:" param; do
  case "${param}" in
    r)
      r=${OPTARG}
      ;;
    e)
      e=${OPTARG}
      ;;
    *)
      usage
      ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND -1))

if [ -z "${r}" ] || [[ !(${r} =~ [[:alnum:]]/[[:alnum:]]) ]] || [ -z "${e}" ]; then
  usage
fi

key_match="\"key\":\"([^\"]+)\""
key_url="https://api.travis-ci.org/repos/${r}/key"
request_result=$(curl --silent $key_url)

if [[ !($request_result =~ $key_match) ]]; then
  echo "Couldn't retrieve key from ${key_url}. "
  usage
fi

echo -n "${e}" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey <(echo -e "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}") | openssl base64 -A
echo
```

It can also be found in this [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/openscript/082bd53b28505337510d9e69386b5fc5).